# Spectral gaps for spin manifold Laplace spectrum

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, spin-geometry

For a (compact) spin manifold, we know that the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ of the Dirac operator are countable, with finite multiplicity, and satisfy 
$$
|\lambda_n| \to \infty, ~~~ \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$
This can be concluded, for example, from the fact that they have compact resolvent, as established in Friedrich's book on Dirac operators in Chapter 4.2.

I am wondering for the gap between the eigenvalues, as we tend to infinity, will it become as large as we want, or at least is there a minimum distance between succesive eigenvalues.

(Honestly, I care most about Hermitian manifolds that are spin, so if it is easier in this case, please let me know!)

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Could you be a bit more explicit concerning your statement "the eigenvalues [...] tend to infinity since it is an elliptic differential operator"? As this is currently worded it seems to be a rule of thumb rather than a mathematical theorem. Could you, maybe, add a reference or a detailed statement of the result that you use here?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have edited to make more clear.

Comment: In the case of a round sphere, the eigenvalues of the Dirac operator have distance 1, which means that the gaps for the Laplace operator (between $\lambda^2$ and $(\lambda+1)^2$) indeed tend to infinity. But to the best of my knowledge, this is very far from the generic case.

Comment: But for the easier question, in general, will there a minimal bound between eigenvalues? Or is there an example where eigenvalues can be as close as we want?

Comment: If for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the $n$-the power of the resolvent of the Laplace operator maps $L^2$ into $L^\infty$, then we can conclude that the $n$-th power of the resolvent is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator - which gives you some information on how far the eigenvalues tend to $\infty$ (but I don't know if the resolvent behaves that smoothly in your setting).

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** In [Eigenvalues of the dirac operator](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0084593), M. Atiyah, 1984, the following results are stated and proved. Let $M$ be a $d$-dimensional closed spin manifold, and $D$ the Dirac operator associated to a Hermitian bundle $V$ with a connection over $M$. Let $\lambda_k$ be its eigenvalues, ordered by absolute value and increasing. The following results are named after their version in the above paper.

> **Theorem 2.**
>
> There exists a constant $C$ independent of $V$ such that
>   $$|\lambda_k|\leq Ck^{1/d}.$$

‎

> **Theorem 1*.**
>   If $d$ is odd, there exists a constant $C$ independent of $V$ such that every interval of length $C$ contains an eigenvalue.

‎

> **Theorem 2*.**
>   If $d$ is odd, there exists a constant $C$ independent of $V$ such that every interval of length $Ck^{1/d}$ contains at least $k$ eigenvalues.

About the case of even-dimensional manifolds, Atiyah gives an argument showing that such a constant would have to depend on $V$, but I don't think it rules out similar theorems for fixed $V$.

---

Out of transparency, here is my previous answer, which in the odd case is of course way worse. It seems classical, although I cannot seem to be able to find a reference with a complete proof (Atiyah writes a sentence about it in the above article), that the Dirac operator on a closed spin manifold $M$ of dimension $d$ satisfies a [Weyl type law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law):
$$\frac{N(\lambda)}{|\lambda|^d}\to C$$
for some known constant $C>0$ ($C_d\mathrm{Vol}(M)$, for $C_d$ a constant depending only on $d$), where $N(\lambda)$ is the number of eigenvalues with absolute value less than $\lambda$ (counted with multiplicity). I claimed before that it implied that the gap between two consecutive eigenvalues cannot be bounded below. In fact, we get
$$\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{|\lambda_{k+1}|-|\lambda_k|}{k^{1/d-1}}<\infty$$
so for $d\geq2$ the gaps cannot be bounded below *at least on one side.*

However it does not rule out large gaps; it only rules out *relatively* large gaps *in absolute value* in the sense that
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{|\lambda_{k+1}|-|\lambda_k|}{\lambda_k}
=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{|\lambda_{k+1}|-|\lambda_k|}{k^{1/d}}=0.$$
Again,  I don't know if there exists Dirac operators on even-dimensional manifolds with arbitrarily large eigengaps.

A few references: [Weyl laws on open manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310075) (S. Moroianu, 2003), claims that this law is well-known in the case of closed manifolds, and that the case of compact manifolds with boundary is treated in [Spectral  Asymmetry  and  Riemannian  Geometry. I](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/aps001.pdf) (M. F. Atiyah, V. K. Patodi and I. M. Singer, 1975). It is also possible that the result of Moroianu holds trivially in the compact case, see Theorem 3. The more recent work [The Dirac spectrum on manifolds with gradient conformal vector fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701635) (A. Moroianu and S. Moroianu, 2007) states in the introduction that

> [The eigenvalues of the Dirac operator on a closed spin manifold] grow at a certain speed determined by the volume of the manifold and its dimension.

which I read as “the Weyl law holds for the Dirac operator on compact spin manifolds.” I bet someone with more experience with Dirac operators than myself will be able to find the missing pieces.